# Python 3.5.1 - variable returns none

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype

My question is regarding some code that is part of an Udacity assignment. The following code is not returning any value. I assume that I'm not calling the "scalar" function properly from my "normalized" function. The line `norm = self.scalar(scale)` returns type none. Can someone give me a pointer?

Code:

```
import math 
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

getcontext().prec = 10

class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, coordinates):
        try:
            if not coordinates:
                raise ValueError
            self.coordinates = tuple([Decimal(x) for x in coordinates])
            self.dimension = len(self.coordinates)

        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('The coordinates must be nonempty')

        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError('The coordinates must be an iterable')

    def __eq__(self, v):
        return self.coordinates == v.coordinates
    def scalar(self, c):
        new_coordinates = [Decimal(c)*x for x in self.coordinates]
        #new_coordinates = []
        #n = len(self.coordinates)
        #for i in range(n):
        #    new_coordinates.append(self.coordinates[i] * c)
        #print(Vector(new_coordinates))

    def magnitude(self):
        new_sq = [x**2 for x in self.coordinates]
        new_mag = math.sqrt(sum(new_sq))
        return (new_mag)

    def normalized(self):
        magnitude = self.magnitude()
        scale = 1/magnitude
        print(scale)
        norm = self.scalar(scale)
        #print(type(norm))
        print(norm)
        return (norm)

my_vector = Vector([1,2])  
Vector.normalized(my_vector)
```

Comment: Well, is there a return statement in the scalar method?

Comment: Is that a legal way to import? This may not be the source of your problem but shouldn't it be: ``import math`` on one line and ``from decimal import Decimal, getcontext`` on its own line?

Comment: @Igor I think it was a copy-paste issue, it was probably supposed to be `import math; from decimal import ..` where `;` is a newline

Comment: @NickHumrich It's because Blckknght tried to fix a formatting issue that caused the top and bottom parts of the code to not be formatted as such. Since the author did not end their lines of code with two spaces, it meant that a space was inserted between them instead of a newline.

Comment: @GarethPW I fixed the formatting

Comment: @NickHumrich: Thanks for fixing the formatting - I'll make sure the code is formatted properly next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python has this cool little *trick* where it will always return None if not specified. So if you write a function hello world that doesn't return anything you will get None.

for example:

```
def hello_world():
  print('hello world')

result = hello_world()
print(result)  # prints nothing cause result==None
```

You dont have a return statement in your `scalar` method, so it will always return None.

My guess is that you want to return the object you create in scalar

```
def scalar(self, c):
    new_coordinates = [Decimal(c)*x for x in self.coordinates]
    return new_coordinates
```

Or for brevity

```
def scalar(self, c):
    return [Decimal(c)*x for x in self.coordinates]
```

Comment: In other words, changing `new_coordinates = ...` in your `scalar` method to `return ...` will solve this issue.

Comment: @o_o Added this into the answer

Comment: Thanks to everyone - the missing return line was the root cause. I appreciate the help & patience with an absolute beginner.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to get a value from `scalar` even though it doesn't return anything. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to return so you'll have to deal with that yourself.

One notable issue is with your method calling the attribute of the `my_vector` instance. It's not technically the issue, but it should probably be changed. Your code should be the following.

```
my_vector = Vector([1,2])

my_vector.normalized()
```

Comment: not the root if the issue, but is an issue I admit.

Comment: Is this technically an issue? Calling a class method from the class with an instance of the class as the first argument will apply the function with the instance as `self`. While the author probably doesn't want to be using the function in this way, it's not really "wrong."

Comment: @o_o I suppose you're correct. This would have probably been better as a comment.

Comment: @GarethPW: Thanks for pointing this out. I appreciate the feedback!